# How to use function for each items of multiple array

Tags: python

I have array such as `[['C'],['F','D'],['B']]`

Now I want to use functino for each items in multiple array.

The result I want is like this `[[myfunc('C')],[myfunc('F'),myfunc('D')],[myfunc('B')]]`

At first I tried like this. However, it did not give me the output I was expecting:

```
[myfunc(k) for k in [i for i in chordsFromGetSet]]
```

What is the best solution for this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You need to call `myfunc()` in the nested list comprehension, not in the outer list comprehension.

```
[[myfunc(k) for k in sublist] for sublist in chordsFromGetSet]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is actually pretty close. What your current list comprehension is doing is iterating over your outer list and returning each item and then calling `myfunc` on each of those lists. To, call `myfunc` on each element in each inner list, do this:

```
[myfunc(k) for i in chordsFromGetSet for k in i]
```

Of course, this won't preserve the structure of your object. To do that, you need to create a new list from the output of `myfunc` for each list in your list-of-lists:

```
[[myfunc(k) for k in i] for i in chordsFromGetSet]
```

Comment: I think this will flatten the result.

Comment: @Barmar I noticed that as well. I edited my answer to reflect the change.